# $V_4\triangleleft S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $V_4:=\{(1\,2)(3\,4),(1\,3)(2\,4),(1\,4)(2\,3),\iota\} \leq S_4$.

> It is possible to show $V_4\triangleleft S_4$ by considering conjugation.

However, after long thought on the matter, I don't see how one verifies that
$$
v\in V_4,\sigma\in S_4\implies\sigma v\sigma^{-1}\in V_4
$$
without trying all possibilities. Of course this is trivial if $a=\iota$, and I suspect there must be an easy general argument.

Comment: $S_4$ is generated by (for example) $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(1,2)$, so you need only check those two elements.

Comment: Of course the more interesting way to show this is this: The symmetry group of the cube is $S_4$ (it faithfully permutes the four spacial diagonals of the cube). It also acts on the three coordinate axesm thereby giving rise to a homomorphism, $S_4\to S_4$. The kernel consists of the 180° rotations around the coordinate axes (and the identity), which is $V_4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: In $S_n$, two permutations have the same cycle type if and only if they are conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
if $v=(a,b,...,c)..(d,e,...,f),u \in S_n$ then $uvu^{-1}= (u(1),u(2),........,u(c))..(u(d),u(e),..,u(f))$.
Use this fact to prove $V_4 \triangleleft S_4$.

Comment: At first I didn't understand your answer, but I think I got it now. In this particular case where $n=4$ and the cycles are $2$-cycles, the result you quote is $\sigma(a,b)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a),\sigma(b))$. Your general result is shown [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) (Lemma $2.4$). Now, $V_4$ contains the identity element and all permutations of cycle type $2$-$2$, and $\sigma (a,b)(c,d)\sigma^{-1}=\sigma (a,b)\sigma^{-1}\sigma (c,d)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a),\sigma(b))(\sigma(c),\sigma(d))$ is also of cycle type $2$-$2$, therefore it's in $V_4$.

Answer (score 1):

$V_4$ consists of all the permutations with cycle length $(2,2)$ and the neutral element.